# How to get the rendering of scene is done with qt3d?

Tags: c++, qt3d

My program do the capture of scene well, but on weak hardware I see somethimes half-image black. I expect this is caused by situation when I do the capture before rendering of scene is complete. My question is how to capture the screen to image in proper moments? or, in other words, how to get when the rendering is completed?

Comment: What do you mean by "capture of scene"?

Comment: the screen shot of current view of scene

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.